# How do I add elements to current page in Flet after appending a new layer?

Tags: python, flet

I'm learning Flet module for Python and I'm stuck with navigation and routing. To add a new page/layer I use page.views.append() to create elements on a new page. But how do I add elements to the page I've just created outside this instruction? Can I interract with current page somehow? For example: inside page.views.append() I create a button "Show current route". It's on_click function must add ft.Text(f"Current route is: {page.route}") to this new page. The button appears on page but function doesn't work. Code examaple (I took it from https://flet.dev/docs/guides/python/navigation-and-routing and modified it to add new button):

```
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.title = "Routes Example"

    def route_change(route):
        page.views.clear()
        page.views.append(
            ft.View(
                "/",
                [
                    ft.AppBar(title=ft.Text("Flet app"), bgcolor=ft.colors.SURFACE_VARIANT),
                    ft.ElevatedButton("Visit Store", on_click=lambda _: page.go("/store")),
                ],
            )
        )
        if page.route == "/store":
            page.views.append(
                ft.View(
                    "/store",
                    [
                        ft.AppBar(title=ft.Text("Store"), bgcolor=ft.colors.SURFACE_VARIANT),
                        ft.ElevatedButton("Go Home", on_click=lambda _: page.go("/")),
                        # This button below appears normally
                        ft.ElevatedButton(text="Show current route", on_click=show_route_button) 
                    ],
                )
            )
        page.update()
    
    def show_route_button(e):
        """This on_click function doesn't add text to current page"""
        page.add(ft.Text(f"Current route: {page.route}"))
        page.update()

    def view_pop(view):
        page.views.pop()
        top_view = page.views[-1]
        page.go(top_view.route)

    page.on_route_change = route_change
    page.on_view_pop = view_pop
    page.go(page.route)


ft.app(target=main)
```

I tried to use page.add() but it doesn't work if I have multiple layers. I can only change page.title(). Is there any way to access current page and add some elements to it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a better way to solve this but I did like this and it works:

```
    print(self.page.views[-1].controls)
    self.page.views[-1].controls.append(Text(f"Current route: {self.page.route}"))
    print(self.page.views[-1].controls)
    self.page.views[-1].update()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try replace your page.add line with the following

```
        #page.add(ft.Text(f"Current route: {page.route}"))
        page.views[-1].controls.append(ft.Text(f"Current route: {page.route}"))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).